# Нужно ли тире после "ниже"?

Tags: пунктуация

Ниже подборка интересных историй

Answer (score 1):

**Тире ставится** в так называемых **эллиптических** предложениях при желании автора подчеркнуть обстоятельство места (что, как правило, сопровождается наличием паузы), например: Вокруг месяца – бледные круги (А.Н. Толстой); Над площадью – низко повисшая пыль, на площади – порожние бутылки казенки, бумажки дешевых конфет (Шолохов); И по всему небу – облака, как розовые перышки... (В. Панова); На бескозырках – пехотные каски (Е. Долматовский).

**При отсутствии паузы тире может не ставиться**, например: Там на неведомых дорожках следы невиданных зверей... (Пушкин); Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали (Фет); В углу старый кожаный диван. В другом углу, позади письменного стола, несгораемый шкаф. На полу ковер (Симонов) (так обычно оформляются ремарки в пьесах).  [Розенталь](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm)

Хотите подчеркнуть паузу - поставьте тире. Но можете и не ставить.

Answer (score 0):

А что на самом деле идет "ниже"? Список или сами истории?
В первом случае после всей фразы двоеточие, во втором - точка.
Если после фразы действительно идут истории, то после ниже, думаю, стоит сохранить тире.
В таком случае логично считать что здесь пропущено слово"приведена" (или подобное).

Comment: Добрый вечер, сами истории.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, я я недописал, интернет замучил. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Если  ниже  идут  сами  истории,  то  почему  точку  не  поставить?  А  то  историю  придётся  со  строчной  начинать.